# page.php opening up in frame when click wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am searching for a way to stop WordPress from changing the page when I click on a link.

Page: http://web318.login-11.hoststar.at/ben/kleinraum/wp/ ->hover over the movie-pic and click on "sample page".

He will change to page.php.

I want the page.php to load up in the black frame, so the whole thing looks smooth.

Any possibilities?

Comment: have you tried using an iframe and setting target property on link?

Answer (score 0):

You have an explicit URL on the href of the link. Of course, this will load a new page. You should replace :

```
<a href="http://web318.login-11.hoststar.at/ben/kleinraum/wp/?page_id=2">Sample Page</a>
```

With a fictious link, like this :

```
<a href="#" id="pagetrigger">Sample Page</a>
```

And then use jQuery to bind the .ajax() function to the click event on #pagetrigger, for example. Fill your target container with the result of your ajax Query. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Hey! I get the links with the wordpress function "wp_list_pages", so i cant just edit it like you said. Now i am that far, that i try to add the "target" to the string im getting back from wp_list_pages, but still it doesnt work. Any ideas? $my_pages = wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&title_li='.$page_sort);
$my_pages = str_replace('<a', '<a target="_blank"', $my_pages);
echo $my_pages;

Comment: Please send the full PHP code of this page so we can better help you.

Comment: hey! just found my solution: in the post-template.php of wordpress i found the permalink-expression, which bakes the later explicit link. when i added the target there it worked like a charm. thx!